# How to groupby a date column level and replace with a column level containing the corresponding iso week number

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with the following column levels:

[image]

I would like to groupby the DATE level to the corresponding iso week number, and have the output equal to:

[image]

I tried the following:

```py
df = df.groupby(
            lambda d: d.isocalendar().week,
            level='DATE', axis='columns'
     ).sum()
df.columns.rename('WK', inplace=True)
```

results in:

[image]

which is part of what I want, but I would like to keep the other levels of the column MultiIndex (YEAR and CAT in this case). Where Year is an integer, and CAT could be string, or categorical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first rename level `DATE` for weeks and then aggregate `sum` per all 4 levels of `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df = (df.rename(columns=lambda d: d.isocalendar().week, level='DATE')
        .groupby(level=[0,1,2,3], axis=1)
        .sum())
```

Comment: It works beautifully. Thanks @jezrael. To make it a little more general case for my application, I made the following small changes:  groupby(level=list(range(0, df.columns.nlevels)), axis=1).sum() and then df.columns.rename({'DATE': 'WK'}, inplace=True).  Many THANKS